# Map + filter - Showing people that have < 18 years and abbreviate names

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I wanted to be able to transform the age into a single array, so I would already know how to filter, then apply the mapping to only show people over 18 years old, in addition, to present the abbreviated names of the people.

```
Example:
 name: "Raul", age: 27,
 name: "Jose", age: 14,
 name: "Maria", age: 52,
 name: "Jesus", age: 17,
 name: "Neo", age: 2

[Ra, Ma] -> Those are above 18, and their names go abbreviated
```

**Here what i tried to do:**

```
const amantesGatos = {  
name: "Raul", age: 27,
name: "Jose", age: 14,
name: "Maria", age: 52,
name: "Jesus", age: 17,
name: "Neo", age: 2
};
// this needs to be filtered

const idade = amantesGatos.age
//i tried to destructuring this array

const nomeAbrev = [amantesGatos.map(n=>n[0] + n[1])]
//Tried to abbreviated names

//Filter above 18
const array = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 444, 17];

function above18(num) {
    for (let i = 18; num < i; i--) {
        if (num < i) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
console.log(array.filter(above18));
```

Comment: `amantesGatos` is a nonsensical input. Is it supposed to be an *array of objects*, instead of one object?

Comment: The key problem is that your input data `amantesGatos` is not valid either as an array of objects, or as just an object. You should maybe [look at the](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) documentation [for each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) to decide which to use.

Comment: @Andy It's a perfectly *valid* object, it's just not what OP thinks it is.

Comment: Take care about data structures. `amantesGatos `

Comment: If you fix your data to be an actual array of objects, you're probably looking at something like `amantesGatos.filter(u => something with u.age).map(u => something with u.name)`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly the desired outcome is `[Ra, Ma]`?

If so you can .filter.map.

```
const peeps = [
  {name: "Raul", age: 27,},
  {name: "Jose", age: 14,},
  {name: "Maria", age: 52,},
  {name: "Jesus", age: 17,},
  {name: "Neo", age: 2}
]
const ofAgePeeps = peeps.filter(({age}) => age > 18)
const shortNames = ofAgePeeps.map(({name}) => name.substring(0,2))
```

You can also chain these...

```
peeps.filter(({age}) => age > 18).map(({name}) => name.substring(0,2))
```

That said your `amantesGatos` is an object with a bunch of duplicate keys and not an array. Which means it's really an object with only the last name and age. For example...

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Tom', age: 2, name: 'Bob', age: 100 
}
console.log(obj) // {name: 'Bob', age: 100}
```

Comment: Should be `age >= 18` lol

Comment: The question has "those are above 18" but if you want "18 and above" then yes, use `>=`

Comment: OP is confused.  Just read the question title.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following

```
let users = [
   { name: "Raul", age: 27,},
    {name: "Jose", age: 14,},
    {name: "Maria", age: 52,},
    {name: "Jesus", age: 17,},
    {name: "Neo", age: 2},
]

let data = users.filter(user => user.age > 18).map(user => user.name.slice(0, 2))
```

data would be `[ 'Ra', 'Ma' ]`